# Finding objects index in a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, multidimensional-array, inventory

Im making an inventory and Im adding stacks but ive hit an issue

below is what I want compared to what works

I just want to find the index of the object I pass through

myArray[0] = [item:object,StackAmmount:int]

```
        var myArray:Array = new Array();
        myArray[0] = ["name1",1];
        myArray[1] = ["name2",1];
        myArray[2] = ["name3",1];

        trace("Name" , myArray[0][0]);
        //traces "name1"
        trace("Stack" , myArray[0][1]);
        //traces "1"

        trace("Index of Object" , myArray.indexOf("name2"));
        //traces -1
        // Not Working (NOT FOUND)

        //How can I find the index of "item1" or "item2" in the above example




        var myOtherArray:Array = new Array();
        myOtherArray[0] = "name1";
        myOtherArray[1] = "name2";
        myOtherArray[2] = "name3";

        trace("Name" , myOtherArray[0]);
        //traces "name1"

        trace("Index of Object" , myOtherArray.indexOf("name2"));
        //traces 1
        //Working
```

perhaps there is a better way of dealing with stacks?

Paste Bin Link: http://pastebin.com/CQZWFmST

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom `class`, therefore a 1D vector would be enough. The `class` would contain the `name` of the item, and the stack. You could subclass this `class` to `override` the `maxStack` variable of the item, and then the searches would be easier aswell, you could just iterate through the `vector` and check the `name`.

```
public class InventoryItem
{
    protected var _name:String;
    protected var _stack:int;
    protected var _maxStack:int;

    public function InventoryItem():void {

    }

    public function get name():String {
        return _name;
    }
    public function get stack():int {
        return _stack;
    }
    public function set stack(value:int):void {
        _stack = value;
    }
    public function get maxStack():int {
        return _maxStack;
    }
}
...
public class InventoryWeapon extends InventoryItem
{
    public function InventoryWeapon(__name:String, startStack:int) {
        _maxStack = 64;
        _name = __name;
        _stack = startStack;
    }
}
```